# Client/server tutorials

Tags: client-server

I've gone through a lot of client/server tutorials.. But I wanted to learn about the client/server chat application. Can someone tell me where exactly do I get a good tutorial? Can someone provide a link?

Comment: [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) seems to be popular. Also, it might help if you specify which language you want to use!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`The Basic Client/Server Chat Application in C#`](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/33396-basic-clientserver-chat-application-in-c%23/)

This should definitely help you.